# SSIS VB.net Script Task to Format Excel worksheet won't run

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis

The DTS statements are underlined like they are not recognized.  This is an older production server so am hesitant to play around with the install, but something seems to be missing.  SQL 2008R2 and SQL 2012, VS 2010, Excel 2013, Server 2012 R2.

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
#End Region

Public Class ScriptMain
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim fileToTest As String

        fileToTest = Dts.Variables("ExcelFile").Value.ToString
        If File.Exists(fileToTest) Then
            Dts.Variables("ExcelFileExists").Value = True
        Else
            Dts.Variables("ExcelFileExists").Value = False
        End If

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What about the `Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime`? Is it recognized? What seems to be missing is the `Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase` and the `<SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()>` class attribute for your `ScriptMain`

Comment: @Filburt  Thanks for the reply, yes the Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime is recognized and your suggestions worked.  Thanks....